# What does 'off the ocean' mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Cpl. Barrett Taylor, a village public safety officer in Nelson Lagoon,
>   saw ash falling early Monday.
>
> "It was raining ash for a little bit," Taylor said. "It turned
>   everything black, the rooftops, the fuel tanks, homes."
>
> The ash was worse Tuesday, he said, because wind coming in **off the
>   ocean** was whipping it around.

[Ash coats village areas near erupting Alaska volcano](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/north/ash-coats-villages-alaska-volcano-1.3512463)

Does this mean **from the ocean**?

Comment: Yes, the wind was coming from the direction of the ocean.

Comment: See this link for an explanation of the phenomena. http://www.britannica.com/science/sea-breeze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*off the ocean* is a shortened form of *off **of** the ocean*, meaning the wind was moving from over the ocean onto the land (or ship or something that is not the ocean).